# Setting a reminder for a message in telethon

Tags: python, telethon

how r u folks ?

I was looking a way to set a reminder for a message to be sent after every 1 minute in telethon.
can I use the currentime variable? if so how do i do that?

Thank You!

Comment: You mean schedule message to be sent after 1 minute?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.